# Growing gliders under rule 110

Tags: reference-request, ds.dynamical-systems, symbolic-dynamics, cellular-automata

I found a glider in the evolution space of rule 110 that grows constantly in size. [Normal gliders](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Juan-Seck-Tuoh-Mora/publication/228632767_Gliders_in_rule_110/links/0deec52ebe40796e4d000000/Gliders-in-rule-110.pdf) live in the so-called ether, e.g. the so-called E-glider:

[image]

Other – often complex – gliders exist in an ether with some kind of radiation (basically A- or B-gliders):

[image]

[image]

Among these I found two rather simple growing gliders:

[image]

[image]

The basic shape of these gliders is the [E-glider](https://comunidad.escom.ipn.mx/LCCOMP/Files/Entries/2013/9/11_20_aniversario_ESCOM_IPN_files/Genaro_IPN_ESCOM20aniversary.pdf#page=17) (see above) which exists in different variants E<sup>n</sup>:

[image]

My question is:

1. Has research been done on "ethers with radiation" and growing gliders?
2. Could it be expected that such gliders must exist?
3. Has the existence of growing gliders to do with the Turing completeness of rule 110?
4. Can there be gliders growing faster than linear?

Comment: Are two gliders going in different directions a growing glider? You don't define what a glider is. The Turing completeness proofs are based on glider interactions and certainly you need two directions for gliders to have interactions.

Comment: And no, gliders cannot grow superlinearly because no information can move faster than at linear rate. (I cannot give a precise proof without a precise definition of glider though.)

Comment: @VilleSalo: Do you have an idea, how a definition of "(growing) glider" might look like? Something like "a growing pattern with an interior not being a growing area of ether"?